# PHP show today's date/time in form drop down lists

Tags: php

i have this long code to show today's date & time in a form drop down lists. It does work fine but I was wondering if there's a simpler way to do it...?

I want to show all months, days, years (only a couple of years), all hours (24 hour format), all minutes and all seconds but have the current date/time selected in each drop down list.

```
<select name="event_month">
<?
$arr_m = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$date_m = date(m);
$count = 1;
$months = 12;
do{
    $month = $arr_m[$count-1];
    if ($date_m == $count) {
        echo ("<option value='$month' selected='selected'>$month</option>");
        } else {
        echo ("<option value='$month'>$month</option>");
    }
    $count++;
}while($count<=$months);
?></select>

<select name="start-day">
<?
$date_d = date(d);
$day=1;
$days = 31;
do{
    if($date_d == $day){
        echo ("<option value='$day' selected='selected'>$day</option>");
    }else{
        echo ("<option value='$day'>$day</option>");
    }
    $day++;
}while($day<=$days);
?></select>

<select name="start-year"><?
$date_y = date(Y);
$year =intval($date_y);
$years = $year+2;
do{
    if($date_y == $year){
        echo ("<option value='$year' selected='selected'>$year</option>");
    }else{
        echo ("<option value='$year'>$year</option>");
    }
    $year++;
}while($year<=$years);
?></select>

<select name="start-hour"><?
$date_h = date(H);
$hour = 1;
$hours = 24;
do{
    if($date_h == $hour){
        echo ("<option value='$hour' selected='selected'>$hour</option>");
    }else{
        echo ("<option value='$hour'>$hour</option>");
    }
    $hour++;
}while($hour<=$hours);
?></select>

<select name="start-min"><?
$date_min = date(i);
$min = 1;
$mins = 60;
do{
    if($date_min == $min){
        echo ("<option value='$min' selected='selected'>$min</option>");
    }else{
        echo ("<option value='$min'>$min</option>");
    }
    $min++;
}while($min<=$mins);
?></select>

<select name="start-sec"><?
$date_sec = date(s);
$sec = 1;
$secs = 60;
do{
    if($date_sec == $sec){
        echo ("<option value='$sec' selected='selected'>$sec</option>");
    }else{
        echo ("<option value='$sec'>$sec</option>");
    }
    $sec++;
}while($sec<=$secs);
?></select>
```

**-- UPDATE --**
here's the cleaner version - thanks!

```
<select name="start-month">
<?
$arr_m = array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
$month = date('m');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $name = $arr_m[$i-1];
    $sel = ($i == $month) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$name</option>";
}
?>
</select>


<select name="start-day">
<?
$day = date('d');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $day) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="start-year">
<?
$year = date('Y');
$years = $year+2;
for ($i = $year; $i <= $years; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $year) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="start-hour">
<?
$hour = date('G');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $hour) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="start-min">
<?
$min = date('i');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 59; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $min) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="start-sec">
<?
$sec = date('s');
for ($i = 0; $i <= 59; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $sec) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: There's so much code smell here my dogs are already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minor optimizations, to reduce the LOC count:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 59; $i++) {
    $sel = ($i == $sec) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>";
}
```

and similarly for the other dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how you are calling the `date()` function:

```
$date_m = date(m);
```

In your code you keep passing a constant such as `m`, `d`, `Y`. This works because PHP is very   lenient in this case, it looks for the constant, doesn't find it and then assumes you meant the string `m` and passes that to the function.

Although the code works, you should still fix the problem by adding quotes around the value you pass to `date()` such as:

```
$date_m = date('m');
```

The reason for this is to prevent any future bugs where you might define a constant called `m`. For example:

```
define('m', 'something...');

// here you would be passing something... to the date function and not m
$date_m = date(m);
```

---

In terms of simplifying the code then @MarcB's suggestion would be good. Another option would be to create a function that will take an array and selected option as arguments, and generate the `<select>` HTML. That would eliminate lots of HTML repetition in your code because instead of repeating the dropdown HTML over and over, you would create an array  and just call your function, e.g.

```
echo getHTMLDropdown($options, $selectedOption);
```